# why USB drive cannot boot from Fedora machine but can from Windows machine?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb, fedora

I have WD Mypassport 500GB USB removable disk. I installed Fedora 20 on it. it **works** fine when I boot it with my **Windows** machine but I **cannot** boot it with my **Fedora** machine.

If I attached it to my Fedora machine, I got the following information. The USB disk is the **sdb**:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000284b3

Device    Boot     Start       End    Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1 *         2048   1026047    512000  83 Linux
/dev/sda2        1026048 976773119 487873536  8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 7.8 GiB, 8338276352 bytes, 16285696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 407.5 GiB, 437553987584 bytes, 854597632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.1 GiB, 499405291520 bytes, 975400960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0008658d

Device    Boot     Start       End    Blocks  Id System
/dev/sdb1 *         2048   1026047    512000  83 Linux
/dev/sdb2        1026048 975400959 487187456  8e Linux LVM
```

From the "lsblk":

```
# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT                                                              
sda               8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 465.3G  0 part 
  ├─fedora-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─fedora-swap 253:1    0   7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─fedora-home 253:2    0 407.5G  0 lvm  /home
sdb               8:16   0 465.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1            8:17   0   500M  0 part /run/media/bow/b9e8c04d-2d7a-4d1d-ba07-9d22c6446a28
└─sdb2            8:18   0 464.6G  0 part
```

When I try to mount the sdb2, I got the following **unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'** error:

```
# mount /dev/sdb2 /run/media/bow
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

**I don't know if above error is the cause of cannot boot from it or not?**

If I use **lvdisplay**, I found there is **no logical volumes** from the USB disk, **sdb**. All logical volumes are from sda. I think it may be not right.

```
# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fedora/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                fedora
  LV UUID                LDrE32-3rWO-X1Yb-I4E2-nSZR-LzLd-OQFwXN
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-02-06 15:24:09 -0500
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                7.77 GiB
  Current LE             1988
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fedora/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                fedora
  LV UUID                doJoNe-EfTs-Bd1r-ZYy0-CaJ3-CYff-o9xxfe
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-02-06 15:24:10 -0500
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                406.85 GiB
  Current LE             104154
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/fedora/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                fedora
  LV UUID                lcIv87-exlt-1jiU-EvMx-KLCM-VaqS-7UtQ0A
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2016-02-06 15:24:17 -0500
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

**Do I need to make a logical volume for it? or the logical volume is there and I need to make it available?**

**EDIT:**

When I boot from the USB disk, the login screen is the same as my Fedora machine with my user name displayed but I don't have that user name on the USB installation.

If I type in my password, error message will show up: **Cannot enter home directory. Using /.**

If I change to use **root**, which is the only user I setup during the USB disk installation, I can login but it is not my Fedora machine, because there is not my existingdata, and also not my USB installation, because I installed **GNOME** for USB disk, but it is **KDE** (my Fedora machine).

**vgdisplay** result (which shows USB and my Fedora machine are under the same volume group):

```
# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fedora
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               465.27 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              119109
  Alloc PE / Size       119109 / 465.27 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               MwYw4n-SnqD-2h2Q-nvrv-BtlO-YFe2-FRwglM

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fedora
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               464.62 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              118942                                                                                    
  Alloc PE / Size       118942 / 464.62 GiB                                                                       
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0                                                                                     
  VG UUID               l8waEM-9nCd-ioT4-bSip-SSBP-mFvQ-AQoy3N
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the internal disk from the Fedora machine, and can you describe the boot process ?  [  It looks to me - but I'm guessing ] that the problem you are having might be the volume group name is confusing the system when it boots up, ie if you have 2 different volume groups both named "fedora"

Comment: share output of  'sudo VGDisplay' pls

Comment: @davidgo, you are probably right. please see my update above. how can I avoid this confusing? I can reinstall the USB disk.

Comment: @linuxdev2013, I update my question with the vgdisplay. you are at the right direction.

Comment: Answeing your question - mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member' - this is not your problem - /dev/sdb2 is part of LVM, and you can't mount an LVM physical volume.  (LVM has physical volumes -> Volume groupls -> logical volumes - you can only mount the logical volumes)

Comment: The problem looks very much like you have 2 distinct volumes with the same volume name, causing confusion for your system.  There is a command "vgrename" which I beleive you can use to rename one of the volumes and remove the confusion, however I equaly suspect that this will cause one of the installations to stop working (ie make it unbootable) unless you can change all the references to it [ which may or may not just be a matter of modifying /etc/fstab ]

Comment: adding to @davidgo's comment.  Sudo vgrename -t /dev/mapper/fedora /dev/mapper/fedora01   < if this  shows no errors remove the '''-t'''  and use VG "fedora" & VG "fedora01" in the future or  find another non conflicting name for "fedora01"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should mount a LVM partition directly? Instead you should run commands like lvscan to probe for the logical volumes and mount the desire one.

The reason it doesn't boot on a different machine can be missing driver in the initramfs. For example, you have an XHCI USB controller on the "Fedora machine" and an EHCI USB controller on the "Windows machine", but the initramfs only included the drivers for EHCI controllers.

You need to give more info on how it does not boot (like, is it a black screen or certain error), otherwise it would be difficult to tell the actual reason.